# Extract the value part from key-value pair separated by colon in Linux

Tags: text-processing, sed, json

I need to fetch `arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:596873354795:demo` from the below content in a file using `sed` command. What would be the command?

Sample file:

```
{
    "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:596873354795:demo"
}
```

Comment: If that is a json fragment, use a json parser, not sed...

Answer (score 5):

Your sample file is in the structured format called [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). `sed` is not a convenient tool to deal with this type of files. Instead install a parser for JSON format, for example [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

To install on Debian-family Linux:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

To install on Red Hat-family Linux:

```
sudo yum install jq
```

For other distributions and platforms check [this page](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/).

---

Then execute:

```
cat sample_file | jq -r '.["TopicArn"]'
```

to get:

```
arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:596873354795:demo
```

Check the examples in the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) for retrieval from more complex files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with line-oriented tools like sed, grep, awk etc AND you only want to do simple extractions of key/value pairs, you'll probably find `jsonpipe` easier to work with than `jq`.

By default, he keys are printed as a `/`-delimited path, separated from the values by a tab.

e.g.

```
$ json='{"TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:596873354795:demo"}'

$ echo "$json" | jsonpipe 
/   {}
/TopicArn   "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:596873354795:demo"

$ echo "$json" | jsonpipe | awk -F'\t' '$1 == "/TopicArn" {print $2}'
"arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:596873354795:demo"
```

---

Details from the debian package of it:

> Package: python-jsonpipe
>
> Description-en: Convert JSON to a UNIX-friendly line-based format
>
> jsonpipe traverses a JSON object and produces a simple, line-based textual format which can be processed by all your UNIX favourites like grep, sed, awk, cut and diff. It may also be valuable within programming languages---in fact, it was originally conceived as a way of writing simple test assertions against JSON output without coupling the tests too closely to the specific structure used.
>
> Homepage: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonpipe